# Prestashop 1.5 Undefined customer default group before logged in to wholesale account

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

We have this error every time we add items to cart before we logged in as customer.

> Notice: Undefined index: customerDefaultGroup in
>   /var/www/....../50/955850fbfbe5eac30bfd4300c8f2e927b58836e2.file.product.tpl.php
>   on line 741 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /var/www/....../50/955850fbfbe5eac30bfd4300c8f2e927b58836e2.file.product.tpl.php
>   on line 741

But after I logged in as customer, the error will be gone.
I know it is related to customer default group as we did add wholesale customer group.

But I am not sure where I can look into. 
Any ideas?

Comment: default product.tpl does not contain this code, show part of code +-5 lines where error happens, you can find it in file `themes/yourtheme/product.tpl`

Comment: Hi sergii,thank you for the hint.